# Sync emails between private ISP and Android phone

Tags: email, android, email-client

I have a question about syncing emails and contacts between an private server and an Android phone.
I can and will change the emails to IMAP but still there is a problem with the contacts. I want them all synced and I don't know how to do that.

On the pc I use Outlook 2003; on the android phone I can install any email client, I've found Aqua Mail and it seems to work just fine.

I saw that the best option for android is to use Google email, but I already have a lot of emails and contacts that I don't want to manually import. Any other options are welcome.

I would still prefer to use Outlook as a PC client but somehow sync the contacts.

Thanks,
Sebastian

Answer (score 1):

If your phone is supported, you can sync the contacts between your PC and an Android phone using [The Missing Sync for Android](http://www.markspace.com/products/android/missing-sync-android.html) (commercial, currently USD $29.95, standard price USD $39.95). It would be independent of the email client, and you could use Wi-Fi or USB for syncing. (Or as suggested, you could switch to Gmail that would handle everything).

Disclaimer: I have used the Missing Sync for Palm long time ago, but haven't used the Android version.

Answer (score 0):

I would bite the bullet and go over to Gmail. You can very easily import both emails and contacts to Gmail. The biggest benefit is that you can easily sync things between your computer and your phone later on (email, contacts, calendars etc).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [Emoze](http://www.emoze.com/download/android) as my default email app mainly because it supports multiple email accounts. It includes the option to sync contacts and calendar from different sources and many other cool features.